# make multiple categories item database structure

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, software-design

Imagine a store with all kinds of different products. Each product has a `category` with many `subcategories`. One can have only one subcategory while the other one can have 3 subcategory. Example from Amazon:

```
Electronics, Computers & Office
    Musical Instruments
        Guitars
            Electronic Guitar
            Acoustic Guitar
    Monitors
    Computers & Tablets
        Tablets
        Laptops
        Desktops
            Gaming
            Home
            Work
```

Monitors has one category level, Tablets two category levels and Electronic Guitar three category levels:

```
Electronics, Computers & Office > Monitors
Electronics, Computers & Office > Computers & Tablets > Tablets
Electronics, Computers & Office > Musical Instruments > Guitars > Electronic Guitar
```

What is the best way to achieve this structure (considering the flexibility, maintenance,
accessibility, etc)?

I saw this:

```
Categories table
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | title                            | caregoty_id |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Electronics, Computers & Office  | null        |
| 2  | Musical Instruments              | 1           |
| 3  | Guitars                          | 2           |
| 4  | Electronic Guitar                | 3           |
| 5  | Acoustic Guitar                  | 3           |
| 6  | Monitors                         | 1           |
| 7  | Computers & Tablets              | 1           |
| 8  | Tablets                          | 7           |
| 9  | Laptops                          | 7           |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

There is only one table, which has a relationship with itself. I don't know if it is correct. Should I go with this idea or I should do it with a more preemptive way by making a `Categories` table like `categores1, categories2, categories3 ...` where they have a `One-To-Many` relationship? The more subcategories, the more tables. But it will be difficult to `SELECT` data from them because we won't know how many subcategories one item has.

Are these correct?

Which one should I use or is there a better way?

Comment: You are on the right track, with own relationship. If you use a column for each categorie; you are limited to a maximum. I would use `0` for the top level, then you don't need to allow null-values. You get the number of subcategories by count its `id` in `category_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that `Nested Set Model` is the best approach to deal with hierarchical data
[image: Categories model]

[image: Categories table]

Comment: Which mean "lft" and "rgt"?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion If we're talking about SQL it should looks like this ...

```
Table(object):  Electronics&Computers & Office
Table(object):Musical Instruments
    Guitars
Table(object):Monitors
Table(object):Computers & Tablets
    Tablets
    Laptops
    Desktops
    Table(object):Desktops
        Gaming
        Home
        Work
```

Totally 5 Tables(objects).Again it'i just my point of view.
Sergei

Comment: And if you want a 5th subcategory? With self referencing you can have unlimited number of subcategories, without design changes.